# Implementing a default equals method for a protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to implement a protocol and protocol extension that provides a default == method in swift. Something like this:

```
protocol NameProtocol: Equatable {
    func getName() -> String
}

extension NameProtocol{}

func ==<T: NameProtocol>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool{
    return lhs.getName() == rhs.getName()
}
```

Then a class like this:

```
class NamedObject: NSObject, NameProtocol {

    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        return self.name
    }

}
```

However, the custom == method is never called:

```
 let one = NamedObject(name: "Name")
 let two = NamedObject(name: "Name")
 if one == two {
     NSLog("EQUAL")
 }
 else{
     NSLog("NOT EQUAL")
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

UPDATE:

From the answers I got it looks like what i'm trying to accomplish isn't really possible. The only way to come close is to subclass (which has its obvious drawbacks). I'm going to keep a lookout for a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `==` operator from the superclass takes precedence over that of the protocol. And for `NSObject`, `==` means pointer equal.

If you remove the inheritance from `NSObject`, it works as expected:

```
class NamedObject: NameProtocol {

    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        super.init()
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        return self.name
    }

}
```

*I can't find any documentation on the order of precedence when there are multiple implementations for `==`. This is just my experience.*

---

**Edit:** instead of defining `==` for the protocol, define your own base class to override `NSObject`'s default behavior:

```
class MyBaseClass: NSObject {
    func getName() -> String {
        fatalError("You must override this method")
    }
}

func == (lhs: MyBaseClass, rhs: MyBaseClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.getName() == rhs.getName()
}

class NamedObject: MyBaseClass {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    override func getName() -> String {
        return self.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to change that behavior? I don't really want to lose the NSObject superclass methods. I'd basically like to provide a default implementation of isEqual.

Comment: Create your own base class to override NSObject's behavior. See my edited answer

Comment: that works, I was hoping to come up with a generic protocol that could be applied anywhere though, for instance i could apply it to a UIView or a regular NSObject

Answer (score 0):

Your class derives from NSObject. You override `isEqual:` (not Swift `==`) to change an NSObject-derived class's idea of what instance equality means.

Your strategy to move this off to a protocol extension, however, can never work because Objective-C knows nothing of Swift protocol extensions. Your code sitting in the protocol extension is completely invisible to Objective-C.

So, basically, by making this class derive from NSObject, you've shot your protocol extension strategy in the foot.

Comment: For an example of how to do it, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37900408/341994

Comment: adding func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool to the protocol extension doesn't get called either

Comment: yea overriding the method works, but i was trying to make a protocol so that any object that conformed to the protocol could use the same isEqual without having to subclass

Comment: "adding func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool to the protocol extension doesn't get called either" Of course not, because _nothing_ you do in a Swift protocol extension is going to get called by Objective-C. Objective-C cannot see Swift protocol extensions or anything in them. — That point has been made on Stack Overflow many, many times (many of them by me). See for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809253/swift-using-protocol-extension-results-in-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instan Added that point to my answer.