# Comparing string array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
text = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

after random:

```
wrongText = ["lorem", "ipsum", "amet", "sit", "dolor"]
```

How do i know which word was misplaced ?
In example above i need only "amet" and "dolor"

Comment: Before posting do some research it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714522/how-do-i-check-in-swift-if-two-arrays-contain-the-same-elements-regardless-of-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var changed = [String]()    
for i in 0..<text.count {
      if text[i] != wrongText[i]{
         changed.append(wrongText[i])
      }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
            
            var changed = [String]()
            for i in 0..<text.count {
                if text[i] != wrongText[i] {
                    changed.append(wrongText[i])
                }            
            }

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
let changed = zip(text,wrongText).filter { $0 != $1 }.map { $0.0 }
```

This will pair the elements of both arrays and output the non-matching pairs. The `map` will extract the first word of each non-matching pair, since you'll only need that.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version that takes advantage of `flatMap` as nil filter:

```
let changed = zip(text, wrongText).flatMap { $0 != $1 ? $0 : nil }
```