# How to compare two Strings to check if they have same Characters Swift 4?

Tags: swift, logic, swift4

I was playing around on HackerEarth and I came across this issue.

What I try to do is to compare the strings and check if they have the same characters or not.

```
var string = ""

while let thing = readLine() 
{ 
string += thing + " "
}

var arrayStr = string.split(separator: " ").map{String(($0))}

var firstString = [String]()

var secondString = [String]()

var cas = arrayStr[0]

for i in 1..<arrayStr.count
{
if i % 2 != 0 
{
    firstString.append(String(arrayStr[i]))
}
else
{
    secondString.append(String(arrayStr[i]))
}
}
print(firstString) //["sumit", "ambuj", "abhi"]


print(secondString) //["mitsu", "jumba", "hibb"]
```

So, now you can see that the first index of `firstString` and `secondString` contains the same character, same for the second index, but not for the last one.

So, how can I compare them? I tried NSCharacter, but HackerEarth is not picking that up. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check in Swift if two arrays contain the same elements regardless of the order in which those elements appear in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714522/how-do-i-check-in-swift-if-two-arrays-contain-the-same-elements-regardless-of-th)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If “multiplicity” counts (i.e. "aab" has the same characters as "aba",
but not the same characters as "abb"), then

```
s1.sorted() == s2.sorted()
```

does the trick. If you don't care about the multiplicity, then just

```
Set(s1) == Set(s2)
```

Example:

```
let firstArray = ["sumit", "ambuj", "abhi", "aba"]
let secondArray = ["mitsu", "jumba", "hibb", "abb"]

for (s1, s2) in zip(firstArray, secondArray) {
    print(s1.sorted() == s2.sorted())
}

// true, true, false, false

for (s1, s2) in zip(firstArray, secondArray) {
    print(Set(s1) == Set(s2))
}

// true, true, false, true
```

For longer strings it might be more efficient to maintain a
*dictionary* with the number of occurrences of each character in
a string (similar to a `NSCountedSet`):

```
func characterCounts(_ s: String) -> [Character: Int] {
    return s.reduce(into: [:], { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 })
}
```

and then compare the dictionaries:

```
characterCounts(s1) == characterCounts(s2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Martin - What do you mean by multiplicity here ?

Comment: @Nawaz: "aba" and "abb" have the same characters ("a" and "b"), but with different multiplicities.

Comment: @Rob13: You are welcome – I have added another option.

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way could be :

```
extension String {
    func haveSameCharecterSet(_ str : String) -> Bool {
            return self.sorted() == str.sorted()
    }
}
```

May be used like this :

```
var str1 = "ABCD"
var str2 = "CDBA"
print(str1.haveSameCharecterSet(str2));
//true
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but I do not know if HackerEarth picks up an extension or not. But, it will be helpful for someone else I guess.

Comment: This should be written as `return self.sorted() == str.sorted()`

Comment: Exactly accepted. will update it. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @Rob13 - Though I am not sure but I think HackerEarth should pick up extension as its a part of swift itself.

Comment: They didn't even pick CharacterSet

Comment: @Rob13: You might need to `import Foundation`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution faster if we deal with "complicated" strings.

```
func isCharactersTheSame(s1: String, s2: String) -> Bool {
    return Set(s1).symmetricDifference(Set(s2)).count == 0 
}
```

For example if we compare "aaaaaaaaa" and "a" for 100 times then `s1.sorted() == s2.sorted()` faster
but in comparing "aaaaaaaaaa" and "a" `Set(s1).symmetricDifference(Set(s2)).count == 0` will win

Answer (score 0):

```
func sameNames(nameOne: String, nameTwo: String) -> Bool {
    var first = nameOne.sorted()
    var second = nameTwo.sorted()
    return first == second
}

sameNames(nameOne: "Pavel", nameTwo: "Maria")
```