# Counting letter occurrences in a String Swift

Tags: swift

Found a cute way of counting the occurrences of character in a String:

```
let inputString = "test this string"
var frequencies : [Character: Int] = [:]

let baseCounts = zip(
    inputString, repeatElement(1,count: Int.max))
frequencies = Dictionary(baseCounts, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

with the result

**["i": 2, "r": 1, "n": 1, "e": 1, "s": 3, " ": 2, "g": 1, "t": 4, "h": 1]**

However I tried to use a range for the elements such that

```
let secondBaseCounts = zip(inputString, 0...)
frequencies = Dictionary(secondBaseCounts, uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

but get the incorrect result:

**["i": 20, "r": 12, "n": 14, "e": 1, "s": 20, " ": 13, "g": 15, "t": 19, "h": 6]**

Why?

Comment: It's additioning the ranges. So for "t", the ranges for "t" are 0, 3, 5, and 11. Summed, it gives 19.That's what's it's calculating.

Comment: the first one is 1,1,1,1,1... the second one is 0,1,2,3,4...

Comment: What is auditioning the ranges? Can't see anything in the docs about it.

Comment: `NSCountedSet`?

Comment: Have a look at `func characterCounts` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52329293/1187415 for a (possibly simpler) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt doesn't implement what you meant to implement. `zip(inputString, 0...)` simply maps the `Int` index of each character to the character itself.

So the value of `secondBaseCounts` will be

> ["t", 0), ("e", 1), ("s", 2), ("t", 3), (" ", 4), ("t", 5), ("h", 6), ("i", 7), ("s", 8), (" ", 9), ("s", 10), ("t", 11), ("r", 12), ("i", 13), ("n", 14), ("g", 15)]

Calling `Dictionary(secondBaseCounts, uniquingKeysWith: +)` sums each value associated with repeating keys, meaning that the values in your final `frequencies` dictionary will be the sum of all indices where a certain character occurs in `inputString` rather than the count of occurrences of that character.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question without using any Build-In methods. Most likely to be asked in Interviews.

```
var inputString = "test this string"

extension String {
    
    func countCharacterOccurances() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
        var occuranceDict : [String : Int] = [:]
       
        for i in self {
            var count = 1
            if occuranceDict[String(i)] == nil  {
                occuranceDict[String(i)] = count
            }
            else {
                count = occuranceDict[String(i)] ?? 0
                count += 1
                occuranceDict[String(i)] = count
            }
        }
        return occuranceDict as Dictionary<String, Any>
    }
}
var characterOccuranceDict = inputString.countCharacterOccurances()
```

> Output : ["h": 1, "t": 4, "i": 2, "g": 1, "s": 3, "r": 1, " ": 2, "n": 1, "e": 1]

The following code is useful if you want a dictionary that is sorted alphabetically by Keys. Otherwise, you can print characterOccuranceDict.

> Problem statement:- "write a program to count consecutive characters in the string and combine them in a string in given order"

```
let sortedDictionary = characterOccuranceDict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
sortedDictionary.forEach { (item) in 
    finalStr = finalStr + item.key + String(describing: item.value)
}
print(finalStr)
```

inputString = "AAABBCCCCD"

Output : A3B2C4D1

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)